# How do you find the next matched element(s), when the set of elements are not always inside the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am modifying a calendar plugin. The plugin adds a class of today to todays date. I would like to add the class of "foo" to "today" and the next 2 days after this.

Rather than each month being 1 unordered-list, the plugin generates a new unordered-list for each row.

What would be the best way to find the appropriate list items when they cross into different parent elements?

Case 1

```
<ul>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day today foo"></li>
    <li class="day foo"></li>
    <li class="day foo"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
</ul>
```

Case 2

```
<ul>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day today foo"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="day foo"></li>
    <li class="day foo"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
    <li class="day"></li>
</ul>
```

I have been looking at .find, .nextAll, .nextUntil but not sure how to do it. Or should I create an array with all the days and then split it at today or something?

Comment: I think you need a condition, if `today` is the last day, or `today + 1` is null, you need to target next `<ul>` and not next `<li>`.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Nope, can all be managed with jQuery's set-based API. :-)

Comment: I see, I know that method but doesn't come to my mind when I comment. Good answer as usual :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find all the days, then find out where in that jQuery set the "today" one is via [`index(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element), and then use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get just that and the two following:

```
var days = $(".day")
var todayIndex = days.index($(".today"));
days.slice(todayIndex, todayIndex + 3).addClass("foo");
```

**Live Example** *(first case)*:

```js
var days = $(".day")
var todayIndex = days.index($(".today"));
days.slice(todayIndex, todayIndex + 3).addClass("foo");
```

```css
.today {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day today">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Live Example** *(second case)*:

```js
var days = $(".day")
var todayIndex = days.index($(".today"));
days.slice(todayIndex, todayIndex + 3).addClass("foo");
```

```css
.today {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day today">xxxx</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
    <li class="day">xxxx</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```